# NTLM request in C# and php

Tags: c#, php, curl, ntlm

I have an ntlm request in C# which works and the same request in php which connects, but returns an error in the response.

Here is the c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/Query/ExecuteReportView");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
            var c = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

            CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
            credentialCache.Add(new Uri("http://example.com"), "NTLM", c);
            httpWebRequest.Credentials = credentialCache;

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"SysName\":\"Callbacks\"," +
                                "\"SysCategory\":\"Eai.CCM.Model.FolderView\"," +
                                "\"StartIndex\":0," +
                                "\"PageLength\":10}";


                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Out.WriteLine(result);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

That works and returns a json string as expected.

Here is my attempt to do the same in php:

```
<?php
$data = array
(
  "SysName" => "Callbacks",
  "SysCategory" => "Eai.CCM.Model.FolderView",
  "StartIndex" => 0,
  "PageLength" => 10
);
$body = json_encode($data);
$headers = array(
    "Transfer-Encoding: chunked",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'example.com/Query/ExecuteReportView');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, dechex(strlen($body)) . "\r\n" . $body . "\r\n");

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

One significant difference, is that the php code is using chunked encoding as the content-length approach kept giving me an error telling me that I needed to specify the content-length or send the data chunked.

Is there anything obvious standing out to somebody that I have missed in my php script?

The php script connects and a response is returned, so I'm clearly not giving it the right information (as I am in the c# version).

This is what the php version returns:

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.Exception","StackTrace":null}
```

I'm using php 5.6.6.

EDIT:

My php script works in php 5.2.17 using content-length instead of chunked encoded data

Same problem in php 5.5.21

phpinfo gives the following for 5.2.17:

```
cURL support        enabled
cURL Information    libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8q zlib/1.2.3
```

and the following for 5.6.6

```
cURL support     enabled
cURL Information 7.40.0
Age              3
Features
AsynchDNS       Yes
CharConv        No
Debug           No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN             Yes
IPv6            Yes
krb4            No
Largefile       Yes
libz            Yes
NTLM            Yes
NTLMWB          No
SPNEGO          Yes
SSL             Yes
SSPI            Yes
TLS-SRP         No
Protocols       dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host            i386-pc-win32
SSL Version     OpenSSL/1.0.1k
ZLib Version    1.2.7.3
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer:

Seems that IIS is doing stuff for me.  Seems that sending header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" tells IIS to do the chunking for me.  So I did not need to chunk the data myself.

```
<?php
$data = array
(
  "SysName" => "Callbacks",
  "SysCategory" => "Eai.CCM.Model.FolderView",
  "StartIndex" => 0,
  "PageLength" => 10
);
$body = json_encode($data);
$headers = array(
    "Transfer-Encoding: chunked",
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'example.com/Query/ExecuteReportView');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```